# Java GUI Exception in Thread while trying to iterate through array list

Tags: java, user-interface, iteration

I am working on a project where I am creating a GUI flip-book. What I want to be able to do is put some text in the text area. Then go to a clean slide. Put in more text. I'm saving all of the "slides" in an Array List. I have buttons on the GUI that will allow the user to go back and forth between the slides. I have ran into an error when I click the "previous" button. I'm getting a "Exception in thread 'AWT-EventQueue-0' java.util.ConcurrentModficationException" error with a whole lot more underneath that.

This code is still under serious construction, so some of it is a little rough. The names of the classes are a little strange - I am modifying a version of a GUI program from a textbook.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;  
import java.awt.*;
//import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;


public class MetricConverter extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel; //To reference a panel
    private JLabel messageLabel; //To reference a label
    private JTextArea kiloTextField; //To refrence a text field - this will become the JtextArea
    private JButton Previous;
    private JButton Menu;
    private JButton Load;
    private JButton Save;
    private JButton Next;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;

    LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();//Created Linked List
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();//Create an array list
    Iterator itr = al.iterator();
    ListIterator litr = al.listIterator();  


    public MetricConverter()
    {
        setTitle("Java Flipbook");

        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buildPanel();//Build the panel and add it to the frame

        add(panel);//Add the panel to the frame's content pane

        setVisible(true);//Display the window

    }
    /* The build panel label method adds a label, a text field, and a button to a panel    */         
    private void buildPanel()
    {   //create the buttons
        messageLabel = new JLabel("Make a flipbook!");    
        kiloTextField = new JTextArea(10,15);//Create the canvas             
        //Create a button for the Previous Slide
        Previous = new JButton("Previous");
        Previous.addActionListener(new PrevButton());
        //Create a button to bring up the menu
        Menu = new JButton("Menu");
        Load = new JButton("Load");
        Save = new JButton("Save");
        //Create a button for the Next Slide
        Next = new JButton("Next");
        Next.addActionListener(new Next());        
        //Create a JPanel object and let the panel field reference it
        panel = new JPanel();        
        //Add the label, text field, and button components to the panel.
        //panel.add(messageLabel);
        panel.add(kiloTextField);
        panel.add(Previous);
        // panel.add(Menu);
        panel.add(Load);
        panel.add(Save);
        panel.add(Next);       
    } //end buildPanel class


    private class Next implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String s = kiloTextField.getText();
            al.add(s);//add to array list
            //ll.add(s);//add whatever is in the JtextArea to the linked list
            kiloTextField.setText(null);//"clear" the canvas
        }
    } 

    private class PrevButton implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String s = kiloTextField.getText();//
            //Object element = litr.previous();
            //System.out.print(element);
            //System.out.print(ll);
            System.out.println(litr.previous());
        }
    }         
    // Main Method          
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MetricConverter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Error occured because there is elements in the `ListIterator` (`litr`): `System.out.println(litr.previous());` You can confirm that by doing :  `System.out.println(litr.hasPrevious());`

Comment: From the above comment, I mean there are no elements in the `litr` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable that, you need to declare an Integer variable inside the class(like globally), that would keep track of where the cursor is. That would enable you to move to the previous and to the previous until the first one.

```
public class MetricConverter extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel; //To reference a panel
    private JLabel messageLabel; //To reference a label
    private JTextArea kiloTextField; //To refrence a text field - this will become the JtextArea
    private JButton Previous;
    private JButton Menu;
    private JButton Load;
    private JButton Save;
    private JButton Next;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;

    LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();//Created Linked List
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();//Create an array list
    Iterator itr = al.iterator();
    ListIterator litr = al.listIterator();
    int previousIndex = 0; //<====================================Changes made here

    public MetricConverter() {
         //no changes were made here
    }

    /* The build panel label method adds a label, a text field, and a button to a panel    */
    private void buildPanel() {   //create the buttons
        //no changes were made here
    } //end buildPanel class

    private class Next implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String s = kiloTextField.getText();
            al.add(s);//add to array list
            litr = al.listIterator(); //<====================================Changes made here
            //ll.add(s);//add whatever is in the JtextArea to the linked list
            kiloTextField.setText(null);//"clear" the canvas

            //navigates to the last Object in the list
            while (litr.hasNext()) { //<====================================Changes made here
                litr.next();
            }
            //keeps track of where the cursor is
            previousIndex = litr.previousIndex();//<====================================Changes made here
        }
    }

    private class PrevButton implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String s = kiloTextField.getText();//
            //Object element = litr.previous();
            //System.out.print(element);
            //System.out.print(ll);
            //System.out.println("arr : "+al.toString());

            if (previousIndex > -1) { //<====================================Changes made here
                litr = al.listIterator(previousIndex+1);//sets the cursor to the previous object's index

                System.out.println(litr.previous());

                previousIndex--;
            }

        }
    }

    // Main Method          
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MetricConverter();
    }
}
```

**Notice** where I made the changes.

Comment: The second chunk of code you gave me works, but it is not what I am wanting to do. The first chunk of code only prints out the first thing I enter. For example: If I type A (then click next), B (next), C (next), (previous), it prints out A, while I want it to print out C. If I click it again, I want it to print out B.

Comment: Please after down voting, a comment would do because this code works as required by the one who asked.

Comment: Thanks Young Millie! I really appreciate it! Now that I have that down, I am trying to make it go the other way also. It is working, but every time I get to the end of the Array List, I am getting an "out of bounds" error. How do I prevent this from happening? Why didn't it happen in your code above?

Comment: it didn't but if that happens in your case, use the if condition(`if (previousIndex > -1)`) to manipulate that.

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs because you have an Iterator but you are modifying its list directly, after it was created. You should only modify the list via the Iterator once you're iterating.

Howevr in general it doesn't make sense to have an Iterator as a member of a class. You need to rethink all this.